# How to take connection from handler and set persistent in custom class

Tags: python, http, python-2.7, tornado

Need advice because I am new to programming, I am making simple multiplayer game (clients are mobile phones and I have C++ code) and I am writing server side using Tornado/Python 2.7. I have defined Python class on server to define player and so on ... My question is when user login via google

```
class GoogleHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler, tornado.auth.GoogleMixin):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        if self.get_argument("openid.mode", None):
            self.get_authenticated_user(self.async_callback(self._on_auth))
            return
        self.authenticate_redirect()

    def _on_auth(self, user):
        if not user:
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, "Google auth failed")
        print(user)
        self.set_secure_cookie("user", tornado.escape.json_encode(user))


class Player(Document):

    def __init__(self, t):
        self._token = t
        self._connection = None
```

how to take that connection and put in Player class, so I can later broadcast messages to all users on that game ( only 3 users can play one game, on server can be lot of games at the moment ). I can am using HTTP request to login and I need persistent HTTP so I can broadcast messages between three players ( to clarify: three players had login and play game, when one send message to server I need to broadcast that message to other two).
Can somebody help with advice how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make an domain process. When you get a message with a `groupid`, you send it to the client(s), then show this message to user.